# Find size of Binary Tree recursively

Tags: recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

I have implemented the function to find size of a binary tree using recursion (referencing a book on Data Structures and Algorithms)

The code snippet looks like:

```
// Returns the total number of nodes in this binary tree (include the root in the count).
public static int size(BinaryTreeNode root) {
    int leftCount = root.left == null ? 0 : size(root.left);
    int rightCount = root.right == null ? 0 : size(root.right);
    return 1 + leftCount + rightCount;
}
```

And it works as well.
However I am unable to understand how the leftCount and rightCount elements get incremented between recursive function calls? Shouldn't it be done like below:

```
// Returns the total number of nodes in this binary tree (include the root in the count).
public static int size(BinaryTreeNode root) {
    int leftCount = 0;
    int rightCount = 0;
    leftCount = leftCount + (root.left == null ? 0 : size(root.left));
    rightCount = rightCount+ (root.right == null ? 0 : size(root.right));
    return 1 + leftCount + rightCount;
}
```

For some reason both the functions yield same result (7, which is correct) for the Binary Tree below.

[image: Example Problem]

Comment: your second version does exactly the same as the first one - you don't magically call `size(root.left)` (and right) more than once - you call it once but as you call the same function you are in again it's called recursive - just imagine you are calling a new instance of this function (with other parameters, etc.) ... so when you finally call it a second, third, ... time `root` and of course `root.left` will have changed and `leftCount` will be a new variable (btw: this will blow the stack for larger trees)

Comment: Carsten, as my question says, I understand its a recursive call. My question was why option 1 works. If recursive calls are Like different method calls in memory, how is the return values getting added?

Comment: no offense meant but I think you don't actually understand how it works - the *return values* get **returned** and you add them right in the last line

Comment: let's look at your example: first `root = 1` (the node not the number - I hope you get it) and so you calculate `size (2)` next (again the node) - now you get a new instance with `root=2` and right on you now call `size(4)` and here there are no left/right children so you return `return 1+0+0` and you end up in the instance with `root=2` - now you do `size(5) = 1+0+0` and finally `size(2) = 1+1+1` ... same with `size(3)` and finally `size(1) = 1+3+3` for your final answer....

Comment: @Carsten No offense taken. I am here to learn. Your third comment was very helpful. I got the same doing it on a paper, after few attempts though. Can you please put in your explanation as an answer? It will be helpful for others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to explain how it works by stepping through your code using
the binary tree you've shown.

You start by calling `size` with the root node (**1**). Its left child (**2**) is not `null` so you call `size` with **2**. Its left child (**4**) is not `null`, so you call `size` with **4**. Now, the left of **4** is `null`, so you set `leftCount` to `0`. The right of **4** is also `null`, so you set `rightCount` to `0`. Then you return `1 + 0 + 0`, which is `1`, to the calling function, which is the one with node **2**. So, the `leftCount`, in the function that was called with node **2**, is set to `1`. Now, we check the right child of **2**, it's not `null` so we call `size` with its right child (**5**). Again, **5** has no left and no right child, so both `leftCount` and `rightCount` are set to `0`, and the function returns `1 + 0 + 0`. Once the call to `size` for the right of **2** returns `1`, `rightCount` is set to `1`. At this point, the function that was called with **2**, returns `1 + 1 + 1`, which is `3`. So, the call to `size` for the left of **1** returns `3`, and we then call `size` with the right child of **1** (**3**). The call to `size` with node **3**, does exactly the same things we've seen for the call with node **2**, so a count of `3` is returned. Finally, the original call with node **1**, returns `1 + 3 + 3`, which is `7`.

If you want a more visual explanation, I've made a video ([find size of binary tree](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C128SsWVLkc) on YouTube) where I first explain the process of finding the size on a high level, then show the code, and run though the code step-by-step with an example (by filling a table with values for variables in each of the function calls, so it's easy to see how the recursion unwinds).

Answer (score 0):

The original code looks correct and is returning the correct answer. Your optional code is just more verbose - it works identically. Remember leftCount and rightCount are separate variables for each recursive call.

The only suggestion I have is to change the name of the parameter passed to the size() function from root to node. This makes it clear that the same function can operate on nodes other than the root node, and the recursion becomes more understandable.